# Not able to build docker image

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, docker-image

```
$ docker build -t jenkins_demo .
```

DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

```
        Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:

        https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
```

Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB

Step 1/13 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS builder

---> 4927d9f3828c

Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /jenkins-plugin-model/src

---> Using cache

---> 7f30d2df21af

Step 3/13 : COPY jenkins-plugin-model/src/Pi.Math/Pi.Math.csproj ./Pi.Math/

COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat jenkins-plugin-model/src/Pi.Math/Pi.Math.csproj: file does not exist

The Pi.Math.csproj is present in Pi.Math folder. Still I'm getting this issue.

This is my dockerfile and I don't have any .dockerignore file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /jenkins-plugin-model/src
COPY jenkins-plugin-model/src/Pi.Math/Pi.Math.csproj ./Pi.Math/
COPY jenkins-plugin-model/src/Pi.Runtime/Pi.Runtime.csproj ./Pi.Runtime/
COPY jenkins-plugin-model/src/Pi.Web/Pi.Web.csproj ./Pi.Web/

WORKDIR /jenkins-plugin-model//src/Pi.Web
RUN dotnet restore

# app image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pi.Web.dll"]
CMD ["-m", "console", "-dp", "6"]
```